# How do I choose between innerText or nodeValue?

Tags: html, innertext, nodevalue

When I need to change a text within a span element, which one should I use and what is the difference:

```
var spnDetailDisplay=document.getElementById('spnDetailDisplay');
spnDetailDisplay.innerText=sDetail;
```

or

```
 var spnDetailDisplay=document.getElementById('spnDetailDisplay');
 spnDetailDisplay.childNodes[0].nodeValue=sDetail;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [innerText vs innerHTML vs label vs text vs textContent vs outerText](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24427621/90527)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For elements with text content, they're the same. See [this MDC article](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/NodeValue) for information on `nodeValue`.

From [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Web_Standards_in_your_Web_Pages/Using_the_W3C_DOM):

> If the element has no sub-elements, just text, then it (normally) has one child node, accessed as `ElemRef.childNodes[0]`. In such precise case, the W3C web standards equivalent of `ElemRef.innerText` is `ElemRef.childNodes[0].nodeValue`.

Answer (score 4):

- **nodeValue** is standard recommendation W3C.
- **innerText** is *Internet Explorer* specific, not the standard. And:

  - Does not return content of `<script>` and `<style>`.
  - Style awareness, does not return text of hidden elements.
  - CSS styling awareness, it will trigger a reflow.

However in versions of all major browsers as of March of 2016 innerText is supported.

In general, they are similar, but if you need the best performance, **nodeValue** should be used.

Link for performance test: https://jsperf.com/read-innerhtml-vs-innertext-vs-nodevalue-vs-textcontent/13