# nodeValue vs innerHTML and textContent. How to choose?

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, nodevalue

I'm using plain js to alter the inner text of a label element, and I wasn't sure on what grounds I should use innerHTML or nodeValue or textContent. I don't need to create a new node or change the HTML elements or anything — just replace the text. Here's an example of the code:

```
var myLabel = document.getElementById("#someLabel");
myLabel.innerHTML = "Some new label text!"; // this works

myLabel.firstChild.nodeValue = "Some new label text!"; // this also works.

myLabel.textContent = "Some new label text!"; // this also works.
```

I looked through the jQuery source, and it uses nodeValue exactly one time but innerHTML and textContent several times. Then I found this jsperf test that indicates the firstChild.nodeValue is significantly faster. At least that's what I interpret it to mean.

If firstChild.nodeValue is so much faster, what's the catch? Is it not widely supported? Is there some other issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [innerText vs innerHTML vs label vs text vs textContent vs outerText](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24427621/90527)

Comment: This question was wrongly closed as a duplicate, since the answers in the suggested link do **not** address `nodeValue` at all. In a situation like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YinCognito/rqjh0ovs/30/), which illustrates the practical differences between `innerHTML`, `innerText`, `textContent` and `nodeValue`, using `childNodes[0].nodeValue` is the _only_ way to get just the text content of the element itself without including any nested elements that it may have - good for getting a label contents without any nested inputs, for example. Take care with closing valid questions, please.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

[Differences between textContent/innerText/innerHTML on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

[And a Stackoverflow answer about innerText/nodeValue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760126/how-do-i-choose-between-innertext-or-nodevalue)

**Summary**

1. **innerHTML** parses content as HTML, so it takes longer.
2. **nodeValue** uses straight text, does not parse HTML, and is faster.
3. **textContent** uses straight text, does not parse HTML, and is faster.
4. **innerText** Takes styles into consideration. It won't get hidden text for instance.

`innerText` didn't exist in firefox until FireFox 45 according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=innerText) but is now supported in all major browsers.

Comment: Uh, `nodeValue` doesn't parse html either

Comment: "Using textContent can prevent XSS attacks" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: so using innerText i can use things like <b>hey</b> and it would be bold?

Answer (score 62):

`.textContent` outputs `text/plain` while `.innerHTML` outputs `text/html`.

Quick example:

`var example = document.getElementById('exampleId');`

`example.textContent = '<a href="https://google.com">google</a>';`

output: <a href="http://google.com">google</a>

`example.innerHTML = '<a href="https://google.com">google</a>';`

output: [google](http://google.com)

You can see from the first example that output of type `text/plain` is not parsed by the browser and results in the full content displaying. Output of the type `text/html` tells the browser to parse it before displaying it.

[MDN innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), [MDN textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), [MDN nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue)

Answer (score 9):

The two I know well and work with are innerHTML and **textContent**.

I use **textContent** when I just want to change the text of a paragraph or heading like so:

```js
var heading = document.getElementById('heading')
var paragraph = document.getElementById('paragraph')

setTimeout(function () {
  heading.textContent = 'My New Title!'
  paragraph.textContent = 'My second <em>six word</em> story.'
}, 2000)
```

```css
em { font-style: italic; }
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">My Title</h1>
<p id="paragraph">My six word story right here.</p>
```

So, **textContent** just changes the text, but it doesn't parse HTML, as we can tell from the  tags visible in plain text in the result there.

If we want to parse HTML, we use **innerHTML** like this:

```js
var heading = document.getElementById('heading')
var paragraph = document.getElementById('paragraph')

setTimeout(function () {
  heading.innerHTML = 'My <em>New</em> Title!'
  paragraph.innerHTML = 'My second <em>six word</em> story.'
}, 2000)
```

```css
em { font-style: italic; }
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">My Title</h1>
<p id="paragraph">My six word story right here.</p>
```

So, that second example parses the string I assign to the DOM element's **innerHTML** property as HTML.

This is awesome, and a big security vulnerability : )

(look up XSS if you want to know about security for this)

Answer (score 5):

**innerText** is roughly what you would get if you selected the text and copied it. Elements that are not rendered are not present in innerText.

**textContent** is a concatenation of the values of **all** TextNodes in the sub-tree. Whether rendered or not.

Here is a [great post](https://kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/) detailing the differences

**innerHTML** should not be included in a comparison with innerText or textContent, as it is totally different, and you should really know why:-) Look it up separately

Comment: What you say about innerHTML is so obvious to me that I sure don't understand why there are so many that did not get it.

Answer (score 2):

[Note: this post is more about sharing a specific data that might help someone than telling people what to do]

In case someone is wondering what's the fastest today:
https://jsperf.com/set-innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-textcontent
& https://jsperf.com/get-innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-textcontent (for the second test, the span's content is plain text, results might change according to its content)

It seems that `.innerHtml` is the great winner in terms of pure speed!

(NOTE: I'm only talking about speed here, you might want to look for others criteria before choosing which one to use!)

Answer (score 1):

Element.innerHTML property to `set`, or `get` element's HTML code.

Ex: We have a `<h1>` tag and strong style with it:

`<h1 id="myHeader" style="color: green"><strong>My Header</strong> Normal Text</h1>`
To `get` content of the element has id equals to "myHeader", we will do the same:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myHeader");
element.innerHTML
```

Return result:

```
<strong>My Header</strong> Normal Text`
```

To "set" new content (value) for this element, the code will be here:

```
Element.innerHTML = "My Header My Text";
```

So this property not only works with plain text, but it is aimed at passing or copying HTML code.

=> We should not use it.

However, many programmers (including myself) use this attribute to insert text into a web page, and this method carries a potential risk:

1. Wrong operation: inserting each text only sometimes deletes all other HTML code of the inserted element.
2. For security: Of course, the two examples above are completely harmless, even if using the  tag is still no problem because the HTML5 standard has prevented the execution of the command line inside the  tag. when inserted into the web page via the innerHTML attribute. See this rule [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0).

Because of this reason, using `innerHTML` is not recommended when inserting plain text, instead use `textContent`. The `textContent` property will not understand that the code you pass is an HTML syntax, but just a 100% text no more and no less.

The result returns if using `textContent` in the above example:

```
My Header My Text
```