# Why is .html() so much faster than .text() when used for the same purpose?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom, jsperf

I was playing around with jQuery's `.text()` and `.html()` methods and running [some simple jsPerf tests](https://jsperf.com/jquery-text-vs-html-query-speed), when I was startled to discover that `.html()` is nearly a magnitude faster at retrieving text:

- `$div.text()` – 88,496 ops/sec
- `$div.html()` – 592,028 ops/sec

Why is `.text()` so much slower than `.html()` when the result is the same? What operations does `.text()` perform that `.html()` skips to account for such a difference?

I know that each method has a different purpose; I am curious about the case where they are used for the **same** purpose.

Comment: I hope you aren't assuming that both functions do the same thing :-?

Comment: No, no, no -- I'm curious why there is such a massive difference when the only inner content is text.

Comment: Alright, we see so many things here... :)

Comment: Hue hue hue... I'll clarify my question a tad. ;)

Comment: I also assume native `textContent` is even faster (if you can trust the text), see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311299/nodevalue-vs-innerhtml-and-textcontent-how-to-choose

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It has to do with the amount of parsing required. `.text()` is slower because it has to parse the interior HTML and strip out any interior tags. `.html()` just grabs (or, if you are setting the content, obliterates) whatever is there and is done.

You can see [the source for `.text()` here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c869a1ef8a031342e817a2c063179a787ff57239/src/selector-native.js#L123) (lines 123-144) and [the source for `.html()` here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c869a1ef8a031342e817a2c063179a787ff57239/src/manipulation.js#L404) (lines 404-441). When simply getting (not setting) a value, `.text()` has recursion, but `.html()` does a simple `return elem.innerHTML;` and is therefore far faster. Even using it as a setter, `.html()` is simpler.

Also note: Even if you use both as setters and pass only plain text, `.html()` is faster; the browser still has to determine `elem.nodeType` when you use `.text()`. This effectively requires parsing the string.

Comment: You can see [the source for `.text()` here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c869a1ef8a031342e817a2c063179a787ff57239/src/selector-native.js) (lines 123-144) and [the source for `.html()` here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c869a1ef8a031342e817a2c063179a787ff57239/src/manipulation.js) (lines 404-441). When simply getting (not setting) a value, `.text()` has recursion, but `.html()` does a simple `return elem.innerHTML;` and is therefore far faster. Even using it as a setter, `.html()` is simpler.

Comment: +1 for getting down with the source. Many thanks, Ed!

Comment: In general use .text when the input is not yours like user input. Use .html when you know the source is safe.