# Getting node value from XML string using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, nodes

I am trying to retrieve the 'code' and the 'value' from an XML string.

I have the following XML string:

```
<items>
    <item>
            <id>55</id>
            <attributes>
                <attribute>
                    <code>ID</code>
                    <value><![CDATA[55]]></value>
                </attribute>
                <attribute>
                    <code>Chip_ID</code>
                    <value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
                </attribute>
                <attribute>
                    <code>FilterKey</code>
                    <value><![CDATA[5]]></value>
                </attribute>
                <attribute>
                    <code>DateTime</code>
                    <value><![CDATA[22/12/2014 12:21:25]]></value>
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
    </item>
</items>
```

I then have the following javaScript to identify each node:

```
var xmlDocument = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
xmlDocument.async = false;
xmlDocument.loadXML(pXML);

var oFirstNode = xmlDocument.documentElement;

var item = oFirstNode.childNodes[0]; //10 of these and they represent the items
 //alert("1 "+item.nodeName);

var ID = item.childNodes[0]; //one of these for each level-ID - NO CHILDREN
var attributes = item.childNodes[1]; //one of these for each level-attributes
//alert("2 " + ID.nodeName);
//alert("2 " + attributes.nodeName);

var attribute = attributes.childNodes[0];//4 of these for each level and they all have 2 children-code and value
//alert("3 " + attribute.nodeName);

var code = attribute.childNodes[0];
var value = attribute.childNodes[1];

alert(code.nodeName);
alert(value.nodeName);
```

I know I am at the correct node as the alert boxes are all giving the expected values.

I now want to retrieve the text for 'code' and 'value' eg the first entry should return code = ID
value = ![CDATA[55]]

I have tried:

```
alert(code.nodeValue);
alert(value.nodeValue);
```

but they are both coming back null.

Answer (score 7):

The `.nodeValue` property of a DOM element is [always null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue).

Use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) instead.

```
alert(code.textContent);
```

I would also suggest using DOM traversal methods that don't require sifting through each individual child node by index:

```
var attributes = item.getElementsByTagName("attribute"); // should contain 4 elements
```

See also: [nodeValue vs innerHTML and textContent. How to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311299/nodevalue-vs-innerhtml-and-textcontent-how-to-choose)

Comment: still no luck, it will not recognise getElementsByTagName

Comment: @user2970105 `code.textContent` seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/o3cp2wc5/ (I'm using jQuery to parse the XML since my browser doesn't support ActiveXObject). What version of IE are you using?

Comment: @user2970105 And here is an example of using `.getElementsByTagName()` to select elements: http://jsfiddle.net/onjs7kLm/

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. For some reason it is treating the value inside the tag as a child of the element, and so nodeValue returns the value I want. Below is my working solution:

```
            var xmlDocument = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
            xmlDocument.async = false;
            xmlDocument.loadXML(pXML);

            var oFirstNode = xmlDocument.documentElement;

                var item = oFirstNode.childNodes[0]; //10 of these and they represent the items

                var ID = item.childNodes[0]; //one of these for each level-ID - NO CHILDREN
                var attributes = item.childNodes[1]; //one of these for each level-attributes

                alert(attributes.childNodes.length);

                    var attribute = attributes.childNodes[0];//4 of these for each level and they all have 2 children-code and value
                    //alert("3 " + attribute.nodeName);

                    var code = attribute.childNodes[0];
                    var value = attribute.childNodes[1];

                    alert(code.childNodes[0].nodeValue)
                    alert(value.childNodes[0].nodeValue)

            }
```