# How to update an element using .textContent

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use a script using JavaScript that updates an  element in the footer of a website. However, the h3 element isn't getting updated.

I have tried [textContent not updating HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329387/textcontent-not-updating-html), but I wasn't able to find my solution there.

Here is my CodePen: https://codepen.io/martinlutherwinn/pen/NWPvRpZ

This is my current code:

```
<div class="Footer">
    <h3></h3>
</div>
```

```
var copyrightedYear = (function() {
    var header = document.getElementsByClassName("Footer")[0].textContent;
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var msg = "@" + currentYear + " Haitian Educators of Palm Beach.";
    header = msg;
}());
```

Comment: Here's a fixed version: https://codepen.io/khrismuc/pen/mdyMrMz?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a new value for `header`, which is a copy of the text in the element. You need to assign to the property to change the text:

```
var copyrightedYear = (function() {
    var header = document.getElementsByClassName("Footer")[0];
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var msg = "@" + currentYear + " Haitian Educators of Palm Beach.";
    header.textContent = msg;
}());
```

Also `copyrightedYear` will be `undefined` unless you have `return msg`.