# Reason why there is no displayed value (DOM)

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm in an entry level javascript course and am studying our Document Object Model section and I am trying to understand the reason why the script below has no value, could someone explain it a little?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body id="bdy">

  <h1 id="id00">Test 1</h1>
  <h1 id="id01">Test2</h1>
  <p id="id02"></p>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("id02").innerHTML = document.getElementById("bdy").childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what's not working?

Comment: Because the childnode is not what you think it is. You need to skip empty textnodes

Comment: For the first element, use `.firstElementChild` or `.children[0]`

Comment: ...and you don't need an ID on the body. Just use `document.body`.

Comment: This was the code example I was given, I didn't need to change anything but understand why the script had no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the childnode is not what you think it is. You need to skip empty textnodes and you likely want to access the [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of the node

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace_in_the_DOM

And here: [nodeValue vs innerHTML and textContent. How to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311299/nodevalue-vs-innerhtml-and-textcontent-how-to-choose)

```js
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("bdy").childNodes.length; i++) {
  console.log(i, document.getElementById("bdy").childNodes[i].textContent)
}
```

```html
<body id="bdy">

  <h1 id="id00">Test 1</h1>
  <h1 id="id01">Test2</h1>
  <p id="id02"></p>
</body>
```

This might be what you meant to do:

```js
document.getElementById("id02").innerHTML = document.getElementById("bdy").children[0].textContent;
```

```html
<body id="bdy">

  <h1 id="id00">Test 1</h1>
  <h1 id="id01">Test2</h1>
  <p id="id02"></p>
</body>
```