# Replacing text breaking radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://www.christmascentral.com/giftcertificates.php

I am attempting to change the text for the radio button options. When running the following script on my page, the text gets replaced fine, but now the radio button can't be selected? The html looks to be exactly the same, other than the text being changed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ChangeLabels() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        console.log(elements[i].innerHTML);

        var re = new RegExp(' Birthday');
        if (re.test(elements[i].innerHTML)) {
            elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(' Birthday', ' Test')
        }  
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    ChangeLabels();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Gah, the mix of jQuery and non-jQuery operations here makes me twitch. `getElementsByTagName(...)` -> `$(...)`, `element.innerHTML` -> `$(element).html()` etc.

Comment: You have to change textContent rather then innerHTML. Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311299/nodevalue-vs-innerhtml-and-textcontent-how-to-choose

Comment: Do you have some scripts for radio elements on this site? It seems you need to reinitialize it

Comment: @IlyaZinkevych Changing textContent gets rid of the radio button altogether unfortunately.

Comment: show your HTML, or create a fiddle to replicate the problem.