# Why linkify with textContent does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache, rest, websocket

Recently, I built a chat. The linkification of content typed into the textarea created some trouble.

```
 if(!String.linkify) {
            String.prototype.linkify = function() {

                // http://, https://, ftp://
                var urlPattern = /\b(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9-+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[a-z0-9-+&@#\/%=~_|]/gim;

                // www. sans http:// or https://
                var pseudoUrlPattern = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;

                // Email addresses
                var emailAddressPattern = /[\w.]+@[a-zA-Z_-]+?(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+/gim;

                return this
                    .replace(urlPattern, '<a href="$&">$&</a>')
                    .replace(pseudoUrlPattern, '$1<a href="http://$2">$2</a>')
                    .replace(emailAddressPattern, '<a href="mailto:$&">$&</a>');
            };
        }
```

1. Problem: Links in chatlog were not transformed, but appear a pure string.
2. Problem: Links contain hidden characters â£https://www.link.com/product/ABC/myaffiliatelink
   When i called the resulting links, I got the following browser notification:

> ```
>   Not Found
>     The requested URL â£https://www.link.com/product/ABC/myaffiliatelink was not found on this server.
> ```

To get the message, I use:

```
textContainer.textContent = message.linkify();
```

Can somebody explain what happens and how to fix this?

Comment: You need to post your code for us to have any chance of figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: You can use either [docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#about-secrets) or [something like this](https://medium.com/@basi/docker-environment-variables-expanded-from-secrets-8fa70617b3bc) using env variables. But as @Barmar said, you have to provide lot more info, at least some code to be able to help you

Comment: Can you give me a directly applicable example?  I'm a little confused as to how 'something' translates into an affiliate link.  Maybe you want to track what links people click on or are you just trying to remove portions of the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking and playing a while with the code, I got the answer. When I use

```
textContainer.textContent = message.linkify();
```

I define the result as pure string. In consequence my linkify function, which adds html-elements such as `<a href="">` is then interpreted as string and thus fails.

The solution is to change the call into

```
textContainer.innerHTML = message.linkify();
```

As a result, the elements are interpreted as html-elements and can be extended. 
More infos about differences between innerHTML and textContent can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311299/nodevalue-vs-innerhtml-and-textcontent-how-to-choose).

Best regards, Joe.