# JS Text change on mouseover

Tags: javascript, text, hover, mouseover

I am beginner to coding and js.  I have been looking to get started on a little project to change text (i.e. the word "cat") to another piece of text (i.e. dog) on hover?  Please help, anything simple to get me started.

Comment: You should edit the question to include what you have tried so far. Otherwise, it's impossible to know where you are having trouble. Also, take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on creating effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are trying to achieve raises the following two basic questions:

1. How do you change the text of an element?
2. How do you trigger this change when hovering over the element?

To answer your first question you may check out [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp) webpage to find out about basic dom manipulation. You can also have a look at the following code snippet to see how to permanently change a text with "cat" to "dog".

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text')
text.textContent = "dog"
```

```html
<p id="text">
  cat
</p>
```

To answer your second question you should read about [eventlistener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp). In this case particular you probably want to use the events [mouseover](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) and [mouseout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp). The following snippet will provide an example of how to use them:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text')

text.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  text.textContent = "cat"
})

text.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  text.textContent = "dog"
})
```

```html
<p id="text">
  cat
</p>
```

Since you seem to be a new learner I could also recommend you to read about [window.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload) since you may be running into some trouble when executing the lines like `var text = document.getElementById('text')` too early.

Also, you could have a look at the [difference between innerHTML and textContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311299/nodevalue-vs-innerhtml-and-textcontent-how-to-choose) as mentioned by [Nick Parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648954/nick-parsons) in a comment. It's actually cleaner to use textContent in this case since we only want to change a text.

Comment: Nice explanation. Since the OP seems to be a learner maybe it would be of use to use `.textContent` rather than `.innerHTML`. `.innerHTML` can have security issues with XSS (if used in other ways), and letting them know about `.textContent` may be beneficial for them down the line.

Answer (score 0):

This code changes the link text to whatever you have in "data-change", and changes it back again on mouse out.

```
<a href="#" data-change="Dog" onmouseover="changeMe(this)" onmouseout="changeMe(this)">Cat</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeMe(el) {
    newText = el.getAttribute('data-change');
    oldText = el.innerText;
    el.setAttribute('data-change', oldText);
    el.innerText = newText;
  }
</script>
```

Test: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MzBQod