# show and hide message below field using onblur

Tags: javascript

I have a form and I want to show an error message if a user has clicked inside the field and then out of it. I have this code and it works perfectly

```
<form action="sign_in.php" method="post" id="sign_in_form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email_3" id="email_3" class="form-control form-control-lg" onblur="check();"
    value="" style="width:455px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
  </div>
  <div id="errorname"></div>

<script>
function check(){
     if(document.getElementById('email_3').value=='' || !document.getElementById('email_3').value.length){
          document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML="this is an invalid name";
      }
}
</script>
```

Now the problem is that if I clicked again inside the field the message is still available. I need to remove the message if clicked inside again until I clicked outside of the field the message comes again. How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `focus` event for empty the error element

```js
function check() {
  if (document.getElementById('email_3').value == '' || !document.getElementById('email_3').value.length) {
    document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML = "this is an invalid name";
  }
}
function empty() {
    document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML = "";
 
}
```

```html
<form action="sign_in.php" method="post" id="sign_in_form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email_3" id="email_3" class="form-control form-control-lg" onblur="check();" onfocus="empty()" value="" style="width:455px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
  </div>
  <div id="errorname"></div>
```

**UPDATED:For Multiple use jquery for more easy**

```js
$(document).on('blur','.validate',function(){
  if(!$.trim($(this).val())){
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.errorname').show();
    $(this).addClass('error_show')
  }
}).on('focus','.validate',function(){
   $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.errorname').hide()
   $(this).removeClass('error_show')
})
```

```css
.errorname{
 display:none;
}
.validate:hover,.validate:focus{
 border: 3px solid #EEA730
}
.error_show:hover{
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #EEA730 !important;
 border:1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="sign_in.php" method="post" id="sign_in_form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email_3" id="email_3" class="form-control form-control-lg validate"  value="" style="width:455px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
      <div class="errorname">error 1</div>
  </div>
  
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email_3" id="email_3" class="form-control form-control-lg validate"  value="" style="width:455px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
      <div class="errorname">error 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Email Address</label>
   <select name="email_3" id="email_3" class="form-control form-control-lg validate"  value="" style="width:455px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
   <option></option>
    <option value="ss">one</option>
   </select>
      <div class="errorname">error 2</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You should use `textContent` in this situation, it would be faster than `innerHTML` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311299/nodevalue-vs-innerhtml-and-textcontent-how-to-choose)

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina .Ya u r  right and Thank.But we don't know him to add string or some html content for error throwing .Thats why

Comment: @prasanth Isn't having the text and/or html in the html rather than updating it with JS better? You can just change the display of the style

Comment: Ok, what if I have multiple fields with a different message and different message place? Should I do many functions?

Comment: Works fine !! Ok, what if I need to add styles. Meaning that I need the field `border: 3px solid #EEA730` when `hover` and `focus`, and if I click out of the field, I need to show `border: 1px solid red` and if I hover without clicking I need to show both `border: 1px solid red` and `box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #EEA730` and if I click I want to remove `border: 1px solid red` and show only `box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #EEA730`. I hope you understand me :( Please...

Comment: WOW !! Literally you are the best ever everything is working as it should. Thank you so much !! 100% accepted answer.

Comment: Oh, I discovered a problem. In option and select the message is shown but when I choose an option the message is not gone ... it only works on inputs and textarea ...

Comment: are you sure.i think its working on select.check update

Comment: Please how can I add to this `$(document).on('blur','.validate',function(){
  if(!$.trim($(this).val())){
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.errorname').show();
    $(this).addClass('error_show')
  }
}).on('focus','.validate',function(){
   $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.errorname').hide()
   $(this).removeClass('error_show')
})` email validation like fliter_validate_email for php but for jquery so if it is empty or the email is not valid show the message ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onfocus` event and create a new function called `hideerror` which sets the `textContent` of your error div to blank (empty string). The `onfocus` event will fire when you click (focus) on your textbox.

I recommend that you use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` as you are not appending any HTML when you display your error message.

See working example below:

```html
<form action="sign_in.php" method="post" id="sign_in_form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email_3" id="email_3" class="form-control form-control-lg" data-error="errorname" onfocus="hideerror(this)" onblur="check();" value="" style="width:455px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
  </div>
  <div id="errorname"></div>
</form>

<script>
  function check() {
    if (document.getElementById('email_3').value == '' || !document.getElementById('email_3').value.length) {
      document.getElementById('errorname').textContent = "this is an invalid name";
    }
  }
  
  function hideerror(elem) {
    document.getElementById(elem.dataset.error).textContent = "";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @BlackP no, you only need one function. Instead, add a `data-error` attribute to your input and set it equal to the `id` of where you want the error to display for that particular input. Then update your function call like I have above

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the visibility of the error instead of constantly changing its contents. Add an event listener for the `focus` event that will hide the error and change the event listener for the `blur` event to show the error when the value is invalid and hide it otherwise.

```js
var errorDom = document.querySelector("#errorname");
var email3 = document.querySelector("#email_3");
email3.addEventListener("focus", hideError);
email3.addEventListener("blur", check);
hideError();

function check() {
  hideError(email3.value);
}

function hideError(flag) {
  errorDom.style.display = flag ? "none" : null;
}
```

```html
<form action="sign_in.php" method="post" id="sign_in_form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email_3" id="email_3" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="" style="width:455px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
  </div>
  <div id="errorname">This is an invalid name</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="sign_in.php" method="post" id="sign_in_form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="email_3" id="email_3"
               class="form-control form-control-lg" onblur="check();" onfocus="hide();"
               value="" style="width:455px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
    </div>
    <div id="errorname"></div>
</form>

    <script>
        function check() {
            if (document.getElementById('email_3').value == '' || !document.getElementById('email_3').value.length) {
                document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML = "this is an invalid name";
            }
        }
        function hide() {
            document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML = "";
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use `textContent` in this situation, it would be faster than `innerHTML` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311299/nodevalue-vs-innerhtml-and-textcontent-how-to-choose)

Answer (score 0):

I've called the check function on `onblur` and `oninput`, so when the value is updated the toast will be removed when it becomes valid.

Below is an updated snippet:

```js
function check() {
  let email = document.getElementById('email_3');
  let errorText = document.getElementById('errorname');
  errorText.textContent = !!email.value ? "" : "This is an invalid name";
}
```

```html
<form action="sign_in.php" method="post" id="sign_in_form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email_3" id="email_3" class="form-control form-control-lg" oninput="check()" onblur="check()" value="" style="width:455px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
  </div>
  <div id="errorname"></div>
```

Hope this helps,