# How to get Image src attribute value using XPath

Tags: javascript, xpath, domxpath

I want to extract the image url from the  tag using XPath but the only problem is it returning whole src attr using the below XPath.

Query used in Chrome inspect tool:

```
$x("//div[@class='specs-photo-main']//img/@src")
```

Output:

```
[src]
0: src
baseURI: "https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_11i_hypercharge-11186.php"
childNodes: NodeList []
firstChild: null
isConnected: false
lastChild: null
localName: "src"
name: "src"
namespaceURI: null
nextSibling: null
nodeName: "src"
nodeType: 2
nodeValue: "https://fdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/xiaomi-11i-hypercharge.jpg"
ownerDocument: document
ownerElement: img
parentElement: null
parentNode: null
prefix: null
previousSibling: null
specified: true
textContent: "https://fdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/xiaomi-11i-hypercharge.jpg"
value: "https://fdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/xiaomi-11i-hypercharge.jpg"
[[Prototype]]: Attr
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Is there is a way to get the "nodeValue" of "src" attribute?

Comment: `document.querySelector("div.specs-photo-main img").getAttribute("src")` ??

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gurmanjot, But I need the value using the XPath rule only and not using javascript, just like we can extract the innerText of a p tag using the //*div/p/text().

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the first element (as you need to get the first node found) and then you can get the properties of the found node:

```js
$x("//div[@class='specs-photo-main']//img/@src")[0].nodeValue
```

Or,

```js
$x("//div[@class='specs-photo-main']//img/@src")[0].textContent
```

if you need to get the plain text value.

See also [nodeValue vs innerHTML and textContent. How to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21311299/3832970) and [innerText vs innerHTML vs label vs text vs textContent vs outerText](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24427621/3832970).