# Issue While Getting innerHTML Text Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code I am extracting the innerHTML text of the html element.

```
if(a.tagName){
if("option"==a.tagName.toLowerCase())
    return a.text.replace(/\u00A0/g," ");
if("select-one"==a.type||"select-multiple"==a.type)
    return this.getSelectBoxText(a,!1);
}
if(this._isIE()||this.isSafariLike()&&!this._isChrome())
    return a.innerText||a.textContent||"";
var b=a.innerHTML;
return!b||-1==b.indexOf("\x3cbr")&&-1==b.indexOf("\x3cBR")?a.textContent:document.createElement?  (b=document.createElement(a.tagName),b.innerHTML=a.innerHTML.replace(/<br[\/]*>/ig," "),b.textContent):a.textContent
};
```

above code return the correct innerHTML text for all HTML element. There is an issue when any HTML element contain text with special character code e.g.
 `<a id="oopID1" href="...">OOP &ndash; Java</a>` [in page is show "**OOP - Java**"].

then it does not return the actual rendered text (mean "OOP - Java").

How could I get the actual value which is getting displayed in the page.
Thanks in advance.
[NOTE : I don't want to use jQuery.]

Comment: probably innerText is what you are looking for.

Comment: Why are you using such complicated script? Can you show a snipet of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `textContent` to retrieve the text content of your element:

```
document.getElementById("oopID1").textContent
```

see fiddle [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zhbbb7gw/1/)

### Useful links:

[**textContent documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

[**innerHTML documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)

[**innerText vs innerHTML**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427621/innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-label-vs-text-vs-textcontent-vs-outertext)

Answer (score 2):

Use `innerText` rather than `innerHTML` as the former gets the value as text, and the latter gets it as markup.