# click on a element of a list html5 javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to click on a element of a list that I create like this:

```
function addlist2(nombre,fecha){

var node = document.createElement("LI");                 
var textnode = document.createTextNode(nombre+"  ");         
var textnode2 = document.createTextNode(fecha); 
node.appendChild(textnode);                              
node.appendChild(textnode2);   
document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(node);     
alert(document.getElementById(nombre).value);

}
```

But I don't know the id of each element that I create.
I want to do different things when I click in different element of the list like open different windows or do different functios:
For example:

Mylist:

DOG

CAT

BIRD

I created this elements when I called addlist2("dog",""); And now I want to show "You have clicked on DOG".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update at the bottom of this answer to adapt to the comments**

You don't really need an `id` for each list item.

Also, depending on your `li`'s content, you might want to use `textContent` in stead of `innerHTML` to check the content. See [innerText vs innerHtml vs label vs text vs textContent vs outerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427621/innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-label-vs-text-vs-textcontent-vs-outertext) for more information on that topic.

<del>**Fiddle (with comments):** http://jsfiddle.net/c19u7074/3/</del>

**HTML**

```
<ul id="lista">
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function addlist2(nombre, fecha) {
  var node = document.createElement("li");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(nombre + "  ");
  var textnode2 = document.createTextNode(fecha);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  node.appendChild(textnode2);
  document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(node);
  // Add a listener to the node
  node.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler(e) {
  // Get node content as a string
  var nodeText = e.target.textContent;
  // Trim whitespaces from the string and check if they match any criteria you like
  switch (nodeText.trim()) {
    case "dog":
      // It's a dog! So do dog stuff here
      alert("woof woof");
      break;
    case "bird":
      // It's a bird! So do bird stuff here
      alert("tweet tweet");
      break;
    default:
      // Else, do stuff below
  }
}

addlist2("dog", "");
addlist2("bird", "");
```

## Update

As you asked in the comments on this answer: opening a window with a fixed URL and variable part depending on the `li`s contents is possible.

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/c19u7074/4/

**Updated Javascript** (only the `clickHandler` function got updated)

```
function clickHandler(e) {
  // Get node content as a string
  var nodeText = e.target.textContent;
  // Open a window pointing to a fixed URL with a variable part containing the clicked item's contents
  // Trim whitespaces from the string and check if they match any criteria you like
  window.open('https://www.google.be/?q=' + nodeText.trim())
}
```

Comment: It works, sorry if my question was no good but I try to click in different li if I add dog cat bird house purple laptot or another thing. The problem is that I don't know what I will add on the list.  For example if I add hello I want to open a new window http:.........?hello                 and If I put asd I want to open http:......?asd

Comment: Yes, hence the `switch` statement, allowing you to change the result of clicking a `li` depending on it's contents.

Comment: But with case before I need to know the words I will put on the list, and I don't know what I will add on the list

Comment: How are you going to decide what happens when clicking a list item then?

Comment: I don't know, I always want to open a new window deppending the word I click.                                                If I click on hello I open http:..........?hello.            If i click on dog I open http:............?dog.              the problem is that I can add different words and I don't want to have all the words loaded on my code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `innerHTML`:

```
function addlist2(nombre, fecha) {
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  node.setAttribute("id", nombre);
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(nombre+"  ");
  var textnode2 = document.createTextNode(fecha);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  node.appendChild(textnode2);
  document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(node);
  alert(document.getElementById(nombre).innerHTML);
}
```

Also you forgot to add this:

```
node.setAttribute("id", nombre);
```

**Snippet**

```js
function addlist2(nombre, fecha) {
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  node.setAttribute("id", nombre);
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(nombre+"  ");
  var textnode2 = document.createTextNode(fecha);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  node.appendChild(textnode2);
  document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(node);
  alert(document.getElementById(nombre).innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<ul id="lista"></ul>
<button onclick="addlist2(1, 'hi')">Click?</button>
```

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/yitemuqebi**

Comment: Thank's you so much :)

Comment: And If I want to do a onclick() for dog, a different for cat and a different for bird?

Comment: @Manumarigle You can use `if` condition this way: `if (document.getElementById(nombre).innerHTML == "cat")`.