# Javascript getting the value of element dosn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

i'm trying to obtain the value of an element with javascript but i'm getting  undefined as it's value even if i know it isn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click "Try it" to display the first array element, after a string split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "a,b,c,d,e,f";
    var arr = str.split(",");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= arr[0];
    alert(document.getElementById("demo").value);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can i obtain the value of "demo" once i changed it?

Comment: A `<p>` element does not have a `.value`. Just access it as `.innerHTML` like you assigned to.

Comment: Btw, probably you want to use `.textContent` rather

Comment: What's the difference between .textContent and .innerHTML?

Comment: The one sets plain text, the other parses html and is a XSS attack vector http://stackoverflow.com/q/24427621/1048572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually setting the `innerHTML` attribute of the `#demo` element, not `value`.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "a,b,c,d,e,f";
    var arr = str.split(",");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[0];
    alert(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<p>Click "Try it" to display the first array element, after a string split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```