# get value of [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to make my son a spelling quiz.
I want to enter his weekly words in mysql with id, word, and weekNo fields
I am using a js text to speech to say the word, and he types it into a textbox. After he submits it there is a function to check if it is correct, then the next word in the mysql row is spoken.
I am getting the next row with...

```
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "getNext.php",
       data: "count=" + $number,
       success: function(results){
         $('#results').append(results);
       }
     });
```

getNext.php

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spelling LIMIT 
    {$_POST['count']},1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<div class='result'>".$row['word'] ."</div>";
    }
```

On the index.php I can display $row['word'] one by one on submit with

```
    <div id='results'></div>
```

My problem is I don't know how to get the value from the ajax call into the TTS, everything I try it says "object HTMLDivElement"

Here is the line where I need to get the ajax value...

```
    var message = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(AJAX.VALUE.HERE);
```

Comment: To make things easier, your API endpoint should really return a JSON or XML file which is easy to parse and use.

Comment: Try to put `console.log(results)` in `success` function and check what is printing in the console elements. It will display tree node and you can able to access the value you want easily.

Comment: Show your whole code if you don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to output the exact word from Next.php

```
echo $row['word'];
```

Do the decoration in javascript when you get the response.

```
success: function(result){
     var word = $.trim(result); // You can use this in your speech engine.
     var wordHtml = "<div class='result'>"+ word + "</div>"; // adding div decoration in JS
     $('#results').append(wordHtml);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get it working with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

According to my guess, you are getting the response from ajax that is an html tag with `id="result"`. You may get the actual value by  ajaxResponse.innerText

In other way, if you are getting output as 'object HTMLDivElement' then that is a div element, and it has property `innerText` to access its value
so final code would be

`var message = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(AJAX.VALUE.HERE.innertText);`

Comment: .innerText solved, thanks!  
More on how javascript obfuscates .value : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427621/innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-label-vs-text-vs-textcontent-vs-outertext

Answer (score 0):

I wirte a php test file of your case:
the html file:

```
<html>
<head>
        <script src=".../jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <button onclick="a()" name="getdata">getdata</button>
        <div id="results"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function a(){
                        $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "getdata.php",
                       success: function(results){
                         $('#results').append(results);
                       }
                     });
                }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the getdata.php file:

```
<?php
echo 1111;
```

So ,I think you problem is at the data formate that your php file returned. You can just return json data, and make the html element in your `html` file.