# How to clear what was echoed into a span tag

Tags: php, forms, reset

so i have an issue with a form made in php. I am echoing an error message in a span tag and i want to clear that message once clicking "clear form" button

This is my php for determining error message when the field hasnt been filled in

```
<script>
function clearForm(){
    document.getElementById("firstName").value = '';
    document.getElementById("email").value = '';
    document.getElementById("lastName").value = '';
    document.getElementById("subject").value = '';
    document.getElementById("message").value = '';
    document.getElementsByTagName("span").value = "";
}
</script>
      <?php
      $confirm= "";
      $firstName = $lastName = $Email = $Subject = $Message = '';
      if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        if (isset($_POST["firstName"]) && $_POST["firstName"]!=null) {$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];} else {
          $confirm ="Please fill it in";
        }
        if (isset($_POST["lastName"]) && $_POST["lastName"]!=null) {$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];} else {
          $confirm ="Please fill it in";
        }
        if (isset($_POST["Email"]) && $_POST["Email"]!=null) {$Email = $_POST['Email'];} else {
          $confirm ="Please fill it in";
        }
        if (isset($_POST["Subject"]) && $_POST["Subject"]!=null) {$Subject = $_POST['Subject'];} else {
          $confirm ="Please fill it in";
        }
        if (isset($_POST["Message"])&& $_POST["Message"]!=null) {$Message = $_POST['Message'];} else {
          $confirm ="Please fill it in";
        }
      }
      if (isset($_POST["Clearform"])) {
        $confirm= "";
      }

      ?>
```

And this is how it looks in body

```
<form name="contact" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="POST">
<p>Your Name: <br>
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="<?php echo $firstName;?>"><span id="confirm"><?php echo $confirm; ?></span></p>
</form>
```

And the code for the button "Clear form"

```
<input class="button" type="button" name="Clearform" value="Clear Form" onclick="clearForm();"/>
```

So i have made this little function that sets the variable $confirm to no content but it doesn't work.

Please help

Comment: You forgot to include the code of that little `clearForm` function, since that seems to be the most important part and what is not working.

Comment: do you mean the javascript code for onlclick event ? if yes then i am adding it but still it is java not php

Comment: I don't think it is Java, I assume it is Javascript and it is really important

Comment: Well you said "*So i have made this little function that sets the variable $confirm to no content but it doesn't work.*" ... so I thought it being relevant. So change `document.getElementsByTagName("span").value = "";` to `document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML = "";`

Comment: @IncredibleHat I tried that and it didn't work. thanks for helping : )

Comment: Sorry, if that didn't work, then I guess I don't follow what you are trying to accomplish :(

Comment: I am doing php form validation and need to echo the error message into a span class, right and then by clicking a button "clear" it  clears the content of that form as well as the error message @IncredibleHat

Comment: Ok. So... why doesn't the answer below by Hossam work? Its basically the same as what I mentioned to change (except he used .innerText instead of .innerHTML).

Comment: I have no clue why it doesn't work

Comment: @IncredibleHat maybe because that span error becomes sticky, not sure

Comment: Once the page is output by PHP, then javascript has FULL reign of all elements in the DOM. You can clear them, you can change their styles, you can even make them bounce around the window ;) So... even though php has echo'd some text into the span... your javascript "clearForm" should have rights now to clear whatever is in that span.

Comment: Just a side tip - You set all the same message to `$confirm`, you'd be better off using an array with all your form elements in and looping it, setting the things which are present, or once setting (for the first time) something isn't present (ideally another array with the form element as a value so you know which things need filling in)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `clearForm()` you shouldn't use `.value` instead, you can use `innerHTML`, `innerText` or `textContent`. To see the difference between them [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427621/innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-label-vs-text-vs-textcontent-vs-outertext)

```js
function clearSpan() {
  let mySpan = document.getElementById('errorSpan');
  mySpan.innerText = '';
}
```

```html
<span id="errorSpan">This is text to be cleared on button click</span>
<button onclick="clearSpan();">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But you see i am creating error message with php, so my concern is how to echo an error message into a span and then to clear it

Comment: @AgnieszkaZimolag in the clearForm() you are getting the span using "getElementsByTagName" which returns an array not a single object hence you can access it by "getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText" or to get the span using "getElementById"

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Use JQUERY .hide() to hide the error.

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
  $("#errmsg").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

```css
#errmsg{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click to remove error.</button><br>
<span id="errmsg">Your error</span>
```