# How to hide closest label If string parameter equals text of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the text in `div.level` equals the text in variable `dlevel` I would like to hide the closest label to that div.

I cannot directly edit the HTML, it is automatically created by the software so I cannot edit the text in div.level. The variable "dlevel" is actually being pulled in from a URL parameter. I can change this parameter (the value of 'dlevel') as it may be an issue with it containing '$'. However, this needs to be versatile so that if the parameter is 50 the label for 50 is hidden and not the label for 500 and vice versa. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var dlevel = '$50'; 

$('div.level').filter(function () { 
  return $(this).text() == dlevel;
}).closest('label').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="level-container">
    <label>
        <div class="level">
            $50
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="level-container">
    <label>
        <div class="level">
            $100
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="level-container">
    <label>
        <div class="level">
            $500
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong approach.

You can loop through the divs `.level` using jQuery `each()` and get the `textContent` of each div.

Then all you need to do is the check if the text equals to the value of `dlevel`, if yes, get the closest label with `closest()` (that traverse up the DOM) and hide it.

```js
var dlevel = '$50'; 

$('div.level').each(function(){
  let text = this.textContent.trim(); //or this.innerText.trim() 
  if (text == dlevel){
    $(this).closest('label').hide()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="level-container">
    <label>
        <div class="level">
            $50
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="level-container">
    <label>
        <div class="level">
            $100
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="level-container">
    <label>
        <div class="level">
            $500
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using .textContent I'd suggest using .text(). Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427621/innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-label-vs-text-vs-textcontent-vs-outertext/24428100#24428100

Comment: Yes, it is another way to get the text, the asker can choose.

Comment: It's not about choice, it's about what's better. .text() will have more cross browser compatibility.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Try $(this).text().trim() === dlevel

Comment: Please, always when answering a question, try to explain to the asker why she should "try this"

Comment: When I tested her code out, $(this).text() had white space around so it did not return true. I am just removing that extra space with trim().

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `each()` like this. You also need to use `trim()` to remove the whitespace. You can use `parent()` to find the label parent of each `.level` as long as the label is always the parent.

```js
let dlevel = "$50";

$('div.level').each( function() {
  if ($(this).text().trim() === dlevel) {
    $(this).parent().hide()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="level-container">
    <label>
        <div class="level">
            $50
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="level-container">
    <label>
        <div class="level">
            $100
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="level-container">
    <label>
        <div class="level">
            $500
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, always when answering a question, try to explain to the asker why she should "try this"

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following using `$.each`**

```js
   var dlevel = "$50";
  $.each($('div .level'),function(i,val){
         if($(val).text().trim()==dlevel)
            {
            $(val).closest('label').hide();
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="level-container">
    <label>
        <div class="level">
            $50
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="level-container">
    <label>
        <div class="level">
            $100
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="level-container">
    <label>
        <div class="level">
            $500
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```