# Text binding between input and span in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-binding

How can I bind input texts to span innerHTML in Angular6?

**ts file**

```
...
finance_fullname: string;
...
```

**template file**

```
<input type="text" id="finance_fullname" [(ngModel)]="finance_fullname">
<span class="fullname" ngBind="finance_fullname"></span>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can say most secure way would be `innerText` or `textContent`.

```
<span class="fullname" [textContent]="finance_fullname"></span>
<span class="fullname" [innerText]="finance_fullname"></span>
```

Even AngularJS were using `textContent` for one way binding. It only `extract` the model value and dump directly inside the specified html node. Even though if you pass `html` it will add that html as a text(decoded html) on the page.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6nv7cu?file=src/app/app.component.html)

`innerHTML` would also work for you, but it could be dangerous, as it will give a chance to inject malicious content on the page in form of html.

Comment: For more in-depth explanations for different html node element text properties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427621/innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-label-vs-text-vs-textcontent-vs-outertext  Note that it is not recommended to use `innerHTML` unless you specifically intend to insert HTML and make the precautions to avoid an XSS attack

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in two ways

(i) You can use **`[innerHTML]`**

```
<input type="text" id="finance_fullname" [(ngModel)]="finance_fullname">
<span class="fullname" [innerHTML]="finance_fullname"></span>
```

[**STACKBLITZ DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g5ivnm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

(ii) Just bind using the two way data binding

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gyyctb?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<input type="text" id="finance_fullname" [(ngModel)]="finance_fullname">
<span class="fullname">{{finance_fullname}}</span>
```

Comment: [innerHTML] working as I expected, but the second one is not working, what is the reason?

Comment: check the demo above

Comment: I checked the demo, it seems you didn't declare the variable in ts file but I declared, that is the reason? The demo is working perfect but not for me.

Comment: yeah that would matter, in that case you use ngModelchange and reassign the value

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you are reading from angularjs since you are working with angular 6.
If you want double binding just do it like this.

```
<input type="text" id="finance_fullname" [(ngModel)]="finance_fullname">
<span class="fullname">{{finance_fullname}}</span>
```

Comment: It's a form? Because If you have many inputs you just put in your ts
form:any = {}
and then in your html [(ngModel)]="form.finance_fullname" and it should work

Comment: I figured out this one, this wasn't working because I declared the variable "finance_fullname" in ts file, once I removed all the declared variables this also working fine. Thanks in advance.