# Why am I not getting the content of this element when I call it by its ID?

Tags: javascript

I want to limit how long a string is when updated by JS. To do so, I want to use a loop that checks the length of the current string and only accepts new inputs if the string is shorter than the maximum length.

For some reason when I ask for the length of the html element, it returns the... nature of the element?

This specifically: [object HTMLParagraphElement]

This is how I'm getting the html element:

```html
const digits = document.getElementById("digits");
```

This is how I'm trying to limit the size, I marked which line I'm currently using to add numbers (it works on its own, I just want to limit how long the string can be):

```
addEventListenerList(numeral, "click", () => {
    if (digits.toString().length > 10){  //(*)
        return null;
    } else {
        digits.innerText += event.target.value; //This is the line that adds numbers.
    }
});
```

So yeah, it's not working because line (*) is finding the current length to be 29 (the length of [object HTMLParagraphElement]). I have no idea how to get the length of the content, and not this... what is this exactly?

I don't know if it's useful, but just in case, numeral is a node list that I iterate through using this:

```
function addEventListenerList(list, event, fn){
    for (let i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
        list[i].addEventListener(event, fn);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing `.toString()` on the element itself, not on its content. Try `digits.textContent.length` instead.

Comment: Welcome.  Please see how to create an [mcve] - most questions (including this one) SHOULD include one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct way to solve this is to use `digits.textContent.length > 10` instead of `digits.toString()`. However, as others have noted, `digits.value.length` and/or `digits.innerHTML.length` may be relevant in some cases.

`innerHTML` is less desirable here because nested html objects or formatting tags like  or  will count as part of the calculated length. It also uses more memory than `.textContent`. See [innerText vs innerHtml vs label vs text vs textContent vs outerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427621/innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-label-vs-text-vs-textcontent-vs-outertext) for a longer discussion on the differences.

Answer (score 1):

You assigned the element to variable not its contents, to get the length of the contents depends on what  element type it is.

If it is a input then you can get the value:

```
digits.value.length
```

If it is another type you can use the innerHTML property:

```
digits.innerHTML.length
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept the answer as soon as the timer is up!

Comment: innerHTML is less desirable here because nested html objects or formatting tags like <strong></strong> or <em></em> will count as part of the calculated length. Value is intended to "set or returns the value of the option ... sent to the server" when a form is submitted. See https://gist.github.com/GoesToEleven/d3bdbb5b5e563fc9cf93#targetText=innerHTML%20parses%20content%20as%20HTML,also%20takes%20styles%20into%20consideration.

Comment: @MatthewLavin fair point, i just wanted to give alternative means as the textContent was already mentioned

Comment: @MatthewLavin I agree with the innerHTML assessment however value length may matter

Comment: @VincentChinner I added your feedback to my edited response.

Comment: @MatthewLavin, thanks upvoted as a comprehensive answer