# What would be a better way (function) to change the color of the number after onclick?

Tags: javascript, function

I am still fairly new to JavaScript and am trying to deepen my understanding of it through mini projects.

In this counter project, I have managed to get the result what I want:

- After clicking the **"add"** button, the counter increment would **increase** and change color to **green**.
- After clicking the **"subtract"** button, the counter increment would **decrease** and change color to **red**.

Below would be my JavaScript code:

```
//create variables to hold the HTML selectors 
var counterDisplay = document.querySelector('.counter-display');
var counterMinus = document.querySelector('.counter-minus');
var counterPlus = document.querySelector('.counter-plus');
//create variable for the counter 
//what we'll use to add and subtract from 
var count = 0;


//create a function to avoid code redundancy 
function updateDisplay(){
  counterDisplay.innerHTML = count;
};

function toGreen(){
  document.querySelector('.counter-display').style.color = "green";
};
function toRed(){
  document.querySelector('.counter-display').style.color = "red";
};

/*-------------------------------------------*/

updateDisplay();

//EventListeners
counterPlus.addEventListener("click", () =>{
  count++;
  updateDisplay();
  toGreen();
});

counterMinus.addEventListener("click", () =>{
  count--;
  updateDisplay();
  toRed();
});
```

I separated the color functions but I feel like there's a cleaner way to write this code i.e conditionals like if statements, however, as I'm still learning I don't fully know how to implement this.

***As mentioned, I'm still learning so a thorough explanation/laymen's terms is greatly appreciated!*

Please let me know for any clarifications or if more info is needed!

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
Thank you those who have taken the time to help me in sharing their solutions!

Comment: What's the question? Is it for a code-review, or is there a specific issue with the current code (eg. unexpected behavior) or some other clarification..?

Comment: I want to know if there is a better way to write a function to change the color of the counter:

EX: 
//function changeColor() {
if (counter increment goes up){
change color to green
}else (counter decreases) {
change color to red};
};
something like that

Comment: There are definitely different ways. Imagine a function like this: `function incrCounter(step) { .. }` with the documentation "Changes the current counter and updates the display depending on movement direction." It might be called like `incrCounter(1)` and `incrCounter(-1)`, respectively. Inside it might look like: `count += step; counterDisplay.innerHTML = count; var color = step >= 0 ? "green" : "red"; counterDisplay.style.color = color;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the following few changes:

- Make use of `let` and `const`. If it doesn't change its value in the future then use `const` else `let`.
- You can create an array of buttons (in the below example `buttons`) so that you can loop over and add `event listener` on all buttons. So that you don't need to add an event listener on each one of the buttons.
- You can use [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to recognize which type of button it is.
- Get rid of multiple functions `toRed` or `toGreen`, instead make a single function that will change the color of text with only one function `changeTextColor`.
- If you just need to change the text of the HTML element then better to use `textContent` in `updateDisplay` function.

see [innerText vs innerHTML vs label vs text vs textContent vs outerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427621/innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-label-vs-text-vs-textcontent-vs-outertext)

```js
//create variables to hold the HTML selectors
const counterDisplay = document.querySelector(".counter-display");
const counterMinus = document.querySelector(".counter-minus");
const counterPlus = document.querySelector(".counter-plus");
//create variable for the counter
//what we'll use to add and subtract from
let count = 0;

//create a function to avoid code redundancy
function updateDisplay() {
  counterDisplay.textContent = count;
}

function changeTextColor(color) {
  counterDisplay.style.color = color;
}

/*-------------------------------------------*/

//EventListeners
const buttons = [counterMinus, counterPlus];
buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const btnType = e.target.dataset.type;
    if (btnType === "sub") {
      count--;
      changeTextColor("red");
    } else {
      count++;
      changeTextColor("green");
    }
    updateDisplay();
  });
});
```

```css
.counter-display {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button-container>* {
  padding: .75rem 3rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.counter-minus {
  background-color: red;
}

.counter-plus {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter-display"> 0 </div>
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="counter-minus" data-type="sub">-</button>
  <button class="counter-plus" data-type="add">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the easiest for me to understand. I do like how the function for eventListener was complied into one for adding, subtracting, and changing color :)

Another new thing I have learn from your code is the `data-type` (in html). 
I was reading it up on this site: 

https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-data-attributes/

but to clarify, is `data-type` an attribute where you can make your own attributes?

Comment: `data-*` is `data-attribute` where you can make your own custom `data-attribute`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Noted! Thank you for clarifying. I will keep that in mind going forward.

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote is quite long but it does the job

I'm not sure what do you want exactly, but here are few notes :

- Use HTML [`onclick`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) Event instead:
  Instead of adding event listener from javascript you can add it in the HTML code like so: `<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>`, and whenever the button is clicked `myFunction()` will be called.
  You can also pass the button as a parameter, for example

```js
function myFunction(element) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Click me</button>
```

- Use [`let`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_let.asp) instead of `var`:
  Variables declared by var keyword are scoped to the immediate function body (hence the function scope) while let variables are scoped to the immediate enclosing block denoted by { } (hence the block scope).
  find more info here: [What's the difference between using “let” and “var”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Comment: Thank you for the tip and link!

To confirm, would var not be acceptable if it is used for global purpose / acceptable as long as it's been hoisted?

Comment: @KO-d14, using `var` is totally fine, it's up to you to decide which best, but in most cases, you don't need to access a variable from out of its block scope `{}`, in this case, `let` is better.

Answer (score 0):

How about something more app based? You can break your whole thing down into a couple key components with a little glue get something that you can easily build on. Its not very different than what you already have, it just sprinkles in some tried and true patterns.

```js
const widget = (element) => {
  const $minus = element.querySelector('.counter-minus');
  const $plus = element.querySelector('.counter-plus');
  const $display = element.querySelector('.counter-display');
  
  let state = {
    color: 'black',
    count: 0
  };
  
  const update = (next) => {
    state = next;
    render();
  };
  
  const render = () => {
     $display.innerText = state.count;
     $display.style.color = state.color;
  };
  
  const onMinusClick = () => {
    update({ color: 'red', count: state.count - 1 });
  };
  
  const onPlusClick = () => {
    update({ color: 'green', count: state.count + 1 });
  };
  
  $minus.addEventListener('click', onMinusClick);
  $plus.addEventListener('click', onPlusClick);
  
  render();
  
  return () => {
    $minus.removeEventListener('click', onMinusClick);
    $plus.removeEventListener('click', onPlusClick);
  };
};

widget(document.querySelector('#app1'));
widget(document.querySelector('#app2'));
widget(document.querySelector('#app3'));
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="app1">
  <button class="counter-minus">-</button>
  <span class="counter-display"></span>
  <button class="counter-plus">+</button>
</div>

<div id="app2">
  <button class="counter-minus">-</button>
  <span class="counter-display"></span>
  <button class="counter-plus">+</button>
</div>

<div id="app3">
  <button class="counter-minus">-</button>
  <span class="counter-display"></span>
  <button class="counter-plus">+</button>
</div>
```

1. First thing you probably notice is that i have multiple instance running of my app. I can do this because I dont rely on `global state`. You can see that when you call widget, it holds its own variables.
2. I have state as an object and the only thing that can write to state is the `update` function. You had something very similar except i combined my state into a single variable and have 1 function in charge of writing to state, and then reacting to it i.e. rendering.
3. Then I have some event handlers being attached that are just calling update with how they want the state to look. This of course triggers a render to keep the ui consistent with the state. This 1 way data flow is very important to keep code clear. The update function can be more sophistacted and do things like except partial state values and spread `state = { ...state, ...next}`. it can get pretty crazy.
4. Lasty i return a function. You can return anything in here, you might want to return an api for a user to interact with you widget with. For example you have a calendar and you want to be able to set the date outside of the widget. You might return `{ setDate: (date) => update({ date }) }` or something. However i return a function that will clean up after the widgets by removing event listeners so garbage collection can reclaim any memory i was using.