# Modern best practice for innerHTML replacement when you want to insert formatted text?

Tags: javascript, html

From what I understand, setting `innerHTML` on an element is bad, because if the new contents come from users, a malicious user can use it to inject `<script>` tags and other harmful content.

As demonstrated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427621/innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-label-vs-text-vs-textcontent-vs-outertext), there are now about eight different alternative tags (with some non-standard).

In my case, I *want* to be able to insert actual html tags like `<b>` and `<i>`, and even `<a>`.

But I never need `<script>` to be inserted.

Is there a standardized best-practice alternative to `innerHTML` using vanilla Javascript?

Comment: You could always give dompurify a try. https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify

Comment: Where is your formatted text coming from? Users? How much HTML do they have available to them?

Comment: Maybe use bbcode instead? https://www.bbcode.org/

Comment: @Ry- Well, it's loaded from the server in JSON files, but shouldn't ever be editable by users. I was just unsure of what the standard practice for this is.
I'll sanitize it with DOMPurify (thanks, @boostedd!)

Comment: If the author of the HTML is the same as the author of the JavaScript, don’t sanitize it on the client unnecessarily. That’s unneeded bloat and/or security theatre. If the HTML is provided by translators or something, sanitize as a step between those source files and the JSON files that the client reads.

Answer (score 0):

There are a million things you can mess up that will allow XSS if you do this yourself. Your best option is a library to sanitize the html for you.

See some options here [Sanitize/Rewrite HTML on the Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295566/sanitize-rewrite-html-on-the-client-side/430240#430240)

After you've sanitized it matters less which property you set.

Comment: Thank you very much, I decided to use DOMPurify, which @boostedd recommended.